# How to make the Bot only work in specific channels?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want my Discord Bot to work only in specifc channels.

```
let channel1 = ["693098853934563367", "693480881867849826", "693480881886759826" ] 


for(let i=0; i<channel1.length; i++){   
  
    if(msg.channel.id === channel1[i]){
      console.log("I am working in this channel")
      //EXECUTE THINGS
    }
}
```

My problem is, that the bot is only woking in the first channel not in the second or third one from the array

Comment: probably in `EXECUTE THINGS` you migh have a return value that leads the for loop to stop?

Comment: Hm yea that might be the case is there another way apart from return that i could use

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a for loop here. As others mentioned, you can use the `some` method, but I think it's probably easier (or more straight-forward) to use the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, like this:

```js
let channelIDs = [ '693098853934563367', '693480881867849826', '693480881886759826' ];

if (channelIDs.includes(msg.channel.id)) {
  console.log('I am working in this channel');
}
```

You can even test it below:

```js
let channelIDs = [ '693098853934563367', '693480881867849826', '693480881886759826' ];
let msg = { channel: { id: 'invalid channel ID' } };

if (channelIDs.includes(msg.channel.id))
  console.log(`I am working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);
else
  console.log(`I am not working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);

msg.channel.id = '693098853934563367';
if (channelIDs.includes(msg.channel.id))
  console.log(`I am working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);
else
  console.log(`I am not working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);

msg.channel.id = '693480881867849826';
if (channelIDs.includes(msg.channel.id))
  console.log(`I am working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);
else
  console.log(`I am not working in this channel (${msg.channel.id})`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) the loop once a condition is satisfied

```
let channel1 = ["693098853934563367", "693480881867849826", "693480881886759826" ] 


for(let i=0; i<channel1.length; i++){   
  
    if(msg.channel.id === channel1[i]){
      console.log("I am working in this channel")
      break;
      //EXECUTE THINGS
    }
}
```

**In ES6** You can use [Array#some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which will stop the search as soon as the callback function is satisfied

```
let channel1 = ["693098853934563367", "693480881867849826", "693480881886759826" ] 

if (channel1.some(id => message.channel.id === id)) {
   console.log("I am working in this channel")
   //EXECUTE THINGS
}
```

Furthermore you can use [Array#includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```
let channel1 = ["693098853934563367", "693480881867849826", "693480881886759826" ] 

if (channel1.includes(message.channel.id)) {
   console.log("I am working in this channel")
   //EXECUTE THINGS
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const channel1 = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

if (channel1.some(id => message.channel.id !== id) return console.log("I can’t work in this channel");
```